# Reusing ThreadPoolExecutor vs Creating and Disposing Ad Hoc?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

I am building a multithreaded process that has a couple stages, each stage iterating through an unknown number of objects (hundreds of thousands from a buffered query resultset or text file). Each stage will kick off a runnable or callable for each object, but all runnables/callables must complete before moving on to the next stage.

I do not want to use a latch or any kind of synchronizer because I don't want to hurt the throughput. I suspect the latch's internals will slow things down with the synchronized counter. I also don't want to use a list of futures with invokeAll() either because I want to start execution of runnables immediately as I iterate through them.

However, creating a ThreadPoolExecutor for each stage, looping through and submitting all the runnables, and then shutting it down for each stage seems to be a functional solution...

```
public void runProcess() {

ResultSet rs = someDbConnection.executeQuery(someSQL);

ExecutorService stage1Executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(9);
while (rs.next()) { 
//SUBMIT UNKNOWN # OF RUNNABLES FOR STAGE 1
}
rs.close();
stage1Executor.shutdown(); 

rs = someDbConnection.executeQuery(moreSQL);

ExecutorService stage2Executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(9);
while (rs.next()) {  
//SUBMIT UNKNOWN # OF RUNNABLES FOR STAGE 2
}
rs.close();
stage2Executor.shutdown();

}
```

However, I know that setting up threads, threadpools, and anything that involves concurrency is expensive to construct and destroy. Or maybe it is not that big of a deal and I'm just being overly cautious about performance, because concurrency has expensive overhead no matter what. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Using some kind of wait-for-completion operation I don't know about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you destroy the thread-pool and re-init a new one it will likely cost you much more than using a CountDownLatch!

Further, calling `stage1Executor.shutdown();` does not promise that all the current threads will finish their execution before the new ExecutorService is up and running. Even calling `shutdownNow()` cannot guarantee it! (and you probably wouldn't want to call `shutdownNow()` because you want your threads to finish executing).

Donald Knuth's once said:

> premature optimization is the root of all evil.

so even if you are not persuaded by me - better listen to him :)

Comment: So if I create 201,331 runnables off the same number of objects (which I count ahead of time), create a countdownlatch with that number, and have each runnable decrement the countdownlatch... wouldn't the countdownlatch choke the concurrency due to its internal synchronization? I am guessing it has an atomic integer or something inside of it that could bottleneck the throughput. And I get premature optimization and all that, but this process is currently single-threaded and it is in need of performance optimization.

Comment: @ThomasN. if you're creating 200K threads then you're doing something wrong: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-Thread-Pool-Performance-Tuning

Comment: I'm not creating 200K threads, I'm creating 200K runnables queued up to execute on 9 threads. I got the impression from my concurrency studies (Goetz' "Concurrency in Practice") that this is how concurrent iterations should be done.

Comment: @ThomasN. great - that's indeed the way to do it! and the way to let all of them finish the 1st task before they starts task #2 is to use a countdownlatch (instead of trying to implement it yourself).

Comment: @Thomas N.: don’t think about the atomic integer within the latch, I promise you, every thread pool executor implementation there is will have *at least* one atomic variable to be manipulated once for each task as well. If you really think that the cost of one atomic update is high compared to what your runnables ought to do, then you have fragmented your operation too much. Switching between the different concurrency tools will never solve such a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up and tearing down a handful of thread pools is negligible.  Try it out in a loop in a test.

Using a countdown latch is fine, but maybe that might just be duplicating the work that ThreadPoolExecutor does internally and *couples* your task to your execution framework.  Not a fan of this approach.

As for the original code, ExecutorService has an `awaitTermination` method so you can wait until your work is done before moving to the next stage.

For my money, your pseudo code is fine.  Just replace executor.shutdown() with `shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService)`, the source for that is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: I may go that approach as I prefer to not have to know the count ahead of time. I would pay admission to see you and alfasin duke it out though.